# Pig xmlloader error when loading tag with colon

Tags: regex, xml, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

Ive been using Pig and XMLLOADER to load xml files. I've been practising on BOOK example. However, XML file I need to process has colons in tag. When I run a script it says that due to ':' it cannot be processed.(exact log at the end)

This is the file I have. Modified for the purpose of ":" case.
BOOKT.xml

```
<CATALOG>
<BC:BOOK id="1">
<TITLE>Hadoop Defnitive Guide</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Tom White</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CLOUDERA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>24.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2012</YEAR>
</BC:BOOK>
<BOOK id="2">
<TITLE>Programming Pig</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Alan Gates</AUTHOR>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Horton Works</COMPANY>
<PRICE>30.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>2013</YEAR>
</BOOK>
</CATALOG>
```

Now this is the BOOK.pig *(note: tried this with regex and Xpath thats why both appear and error is still there)*

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A =  LOAD 'BOOKT' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('BC:BOOK') as (x:chararray);
dump A; 
--B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<BC:BOOK>\\s*<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>\\s*<AUTHOR>(.*)</AUTHOR>\\s*<COUNTRY>(.*)</COUNTRY>\\s*<COMPANY>(.*)</COMPANY>\\s*<PRICE>(.*)</PRICE>\\s*<YEAR>(.*)</YEAR>\\s*</BC:BOOK>'));
B = FOREACH A GENERATE flatten XPath(x, 'BC:BOOK/AUTHOR'), XPath(x, 'BC:BOOK/PRICE');
describe B;
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: XML tag identifier 'BC:BOOK' does not match the regular expression /[a-zA-Z\_][0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+/
```

My question is what should i put in XMLLOADE(*STRING* identifier) so that I can have tags with ":" (  I cannot modify piggybank.jar, i tried putting : as a xml special code,and i tried using XMLLOADER('sth'+'sth')...

Answer (score 0):

One , not so neat solution, is to load  it to pig storage and then to replace ':' with '', and then to load it with XMLLOADER.