# Pig XMLLoader: Cannot parse XML (Converting to CSV)

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, apache-pig

I have the following XML data:

```
<CompactData><my:DataSet><my:Series VAL="A" AMOUNT_TYPE="FI" IDENTIFIER="1"><my:Obs AMT="24.25" UNIT_MEASURE="KG"></my:Obs></my:Series><my:Series VAL="B" AMOUNT_TYPE="GI" IDENTIFIER="2"><my:Obs AMT="21.22" UNIT_MEASURE="KG"></my:Obs></my:Series></my:DataSet></CompactData>
```

I am trying to convert it to a CSV format using the following commands in PIG:

```
A = LOAD '/testing/mydata.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('CompactData') as (x:chararray); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<my:Series VAL="([^"]+)" AMOUNT_TYPE="([^"]+)" IDENTIFIER="([^"]+)"><my:Obs AMT="([^"]+)" UNIT_MEASURE="([^"]+)"></my:Obs></my:Series>')) AS (val:chararray,amount_type:chararray,identifier:chararray,amt:chararray,unit_measure:chararray);
```

Putting the regex `<my:Series VAL="([^"]+)" AMOUNT_TYPE="([^"]+)" IDENTIFIER="([^"]+)"><my:Obs AMT="([^"]+)" UNIT_MEASURE="([^"]+)"><\/my:Obs><\/my:Series>` into [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) gives two perfect matches, but Pig just does not want to work with it. It always gives me an empty result whereas I expect the following:

A,FI,1,24.25,KG
B,GI,2,21.22,KG

Update 1: This seems most likely related to the issue mentioned here: [Pig xmlloader error when loading tag with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939813/pig-xmlloader-error-when-loading-tag-with-colon)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code does not give an error, I can think of 3 potential problems here:

1. Your regex is not called
2. Your regex (in pig) is not returning the expected result
3. The output of your regex is not shown

To deal with the situation, I would recommend the following steps:

1. Create a pig program that succesfully uses regex to find 'b' in 'aba'
2. Create a pig program that succesfully finds both occurrences of 'a' in 'aba'
3. Create a pig program that succesfully finds the firstof 'a' in 'aba'
4. Keep 'growing' this solution gradually untill you reach your actual solution

If you still get stuck, please share the last solution that worked, and the first one that didn't work. (including input!)

Comment: This is actually related to the same problem mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939813/pig-xmlloader-error-when-loading-tag-with-colon